# How to compute the $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have computed the limite of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ as follows:

[image: \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}]

I want to know if with the first two paths -*Path 1* and *Path 2*-, are sufficient to say that the limit does not exist, because the given paths are different -$1 \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

What about the third one?

Is this procedure correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. By definition, the limit only exists if you get the same answer for EVERY POSSIBLE path which approaches the point (0,0).

Comment: Note that $\frac{0}{y^2}=0$ and is not undetermined. As you approach along the path $x=0$ the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Path 1 and Path 2 are enough so yes.
2. State the paths clearly:

Path 1: $y=0$

Path 2: $y=x$

Path 3: $x=0$

3. Path 3 limit is 0, not indeterminate or undefined like the limit below:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2 - (x)^2}{h}$$

It is not determined or undefined. It is $2x$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is enough to conclude from the first two paths that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This means as you get arbitrsrily close to the origin, you have some function values that do not get arbitrarily close to any potential limit (because they get arbitrarily close to some other potential limit)