# How to solve $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So far, this is what I have computed:

[image: \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}]

The first paths give as result $0$, but the fourth one is undetermined.

Some ideas, suggestions to proceed with this exercise?

Comment: Why do you think the limit of the 4th path is undetermined? Hint: $|x^3| \le |x| (x^2 + y^2)$.

Comment: This is very similar to your [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890718/how-to-compute-the-lim-x-y-to0-0-fracx2x2y2). What did you learn from that? Please try to build upon it otherwise it just looks like you want someone to check all your homework for you.

Comment: @IanMiller, thanks for your recommendation. I'm just starting with this topic in Multivariable Calculus; and I want to learn and understand.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkmy87ymziciuuo/MATE-1207%20-%20Taller%20No.%202%20-%203b%20%5B2%5D.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to transform to polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$ for which $x=\rho \cos(\phi)$ and $y=\rho \sin(\phi)$.  Then, we have

$$\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}=\rho \cos^3(\phi)\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,\rho \to 0$$

Comment: @DrMV, So this is correct? https://www.dropbox.com/s/gotdcjc4mo9nmb8/Taller%20No.%202%20-%203.b%20%5B3%5D.png?dl=0

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez That looks fine except for the last line.  Remember that we are approaching zero along an arbitrary path.  So, $\theta$ will depend on $r$ in general.  But we know that the cosine function is bounded.  So, $0<|r\cos^3(\theta)|\le r$ which approaches zero as $r \to 0$.  And application of the squeeze theorem finishes the argument.

Comment: why $\theta$ depends on r?

Comment: When I draw in polar coordinates the direction of $r$ is given by the angle $\theta$?.

Comment: The path is a contour.  For example, suppose we approach the origin along the parabolic contour $y=x^2$.  This is equivalent to $r=\cot(\theta)$, which clearly shows the relationship between $r$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

Your last statement is false : $0/y^2=0$ for all non null values of $y$, so the limit is still $0$.

Problem with your study is that you study directionnal limits : limits when you follow a straight line passing through the origin. This is not continuity, neither limit in the plane.

You have to ensure that the limit is $0$ for every **path** passing through the origin, for example the parabola $y=x^2$ (you you can verify that this is also the case).

One way to do the study is using polar coordinates :
$$\left|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right| = \left|\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta}{r^2}\right| = r\left|\cos^3\theta\right| \le r$$
so when $r$ tends to $0$ (which is a way of saying that the point $(x,y)$ is close to $(0,0)$), $\left|f(x,y)-0\right|$ tends to $0$.

Sorry for my poor english vocabulary in terms of limits and topology :-)

Comment: why the expression $\left|f(x,y)-0\right|$?

Comment: The distance between $f(x,y)$ and its supposed limit ?

Comment: Can I do $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x\lim_{(x,y)->(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=0\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ and that the limit is $0$?

Comment: No. You can't. Because you didn't PROVE that the limit of the quotient EXISTS.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{0}{y^2}$ definitely goes to $0$ as $y\to 0$.

So far, it seems like all the paths you've tried go to $0$, so this gives us an indication that the limit does exist. To show this, note that since $x^2 \leq x^2+y^2$, when $x > 0$ we have $0 \leq \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{x^3}{x^2}  = x$. When $x < 0$, we similarly have $x \leq \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\leq 0$. So, in general, we have 
$$-|x|\leq \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} \leq |x|$$
So since the left and right hand expressions go to $0$ as $(x,y)\to 0$, by the squeeze theorem, the middle also goes to $0$.

Comment: what do you think about this solution? https://www.dropbox.com/s/gotdcjc4mo9nmb8/Taller%20No.%202%20-%203.b%20%5B3%5D.png?dl=0

Comment: That proof is incorrect the way it is, since the transformation to polar coordinates is not continuous on any neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Some care could be taken to fix this while keeping the idea of the proof the same, although your class might not expect that level of rigor.